SQL ODBC connection fails after activating wireguard tunnel
I have a problem with connecting to my DB while Wireguard VPN is activated. The problem appears both when the DB is on my machine (localhost) and when it's a machine on the same network (using the machine name e.g. DOMAIN\SERVER005). The main problem here is with the localhost db so I'd like to start with this.
Wireguard is set to accept the usual peers IP addresses and only one single IP that is used by my Application.
Basically, I'm trying to connect to a remote device via Wireguard and put its data into a DB which, in this case, is on my computer.
Topology here
When Wireguard is off, I can successfully connect to my local DB, but obviously not to the remote device. If Wireguard is on, I can connect to the remote device but connection to my DB fails (timeout). If I start the application with Wireguard off and then I turn it on, the application works (it stays connected to the DB) and I can connect to the remote device, so it kinda works but is a workaround that I don't like very much, or at least that I'd like to understand more.
I already tried using the IP of my machine instead of "localhost" and it seem to work but I need to guarantee that wireguard won't break other softwares which we can't control, so I'd like to understand what is happening.
Why could this happen? Thank you.

connection to my DB fails (timeout). Connect how? Are you using localhost? What happens when you ping the name? What IP address does it translate to?

i try to add a data origin in odbcad32.exe, in the tab System DSN. The error i get is "Connection impossible, SQLState HYT00, SQL Server error 0, access timeout expired". It appears I cannot ping the name of the sql server instance on my pc. Its name is something like PC00x\SQLEXPRESS and when i try to ping it says the name is not correct. I can correctly ping PC00x alone
